# How to make entire form read only Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I wanted to make read only for all the controls inside a form, Are there any way to achieve this in form level property. I can apply read-only for each control and achieve this, but form is very complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to set the form controls with the attribute readonly, then unfortunately no as Angular does not support setting that property programatically. If you're using ReactiveForms, you can set an entire FormGroup to disabled with the `disable()` method.

```
this.form.disable()
```

Comment: When disable you cat not get value of field

Comment: @OPV you can get it through getRawValue()